# Linq To Sql One To Many

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, one-to-many

Say I have 3 tables, `Cars`, `Persons`, `CarOwners`.

`Cars` is just a table of cars and `Persons` are different people that can own cars. `CarOwners` has a `CarId` and a `PersonId` relationship and a `CarOwnerId` PK.

If I just create the relationship and then drag them to the linq context, a property of the `Person` class will be generated called `CarOwners`. To get the cars that this person owns I would have to do the following query:

```
var cars = person.CarOwners.Select(c=> c.Car);
```

But I would like to be able to do:

```
var cars = person.Cars;
```

Is that at all possible? The extra step is quite annoying.

Comment: Does person have a Collection on it that represents the Cars that the person is associated with? Also how is person being populated

Comment: Person is just any random person taken from the DB. The person has a collection of CarOwners, but I want a selection of Cars

Comment: Are you able to add a Cars property to the Person class that does the Linq query for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a new property on `Person`:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public IEnumerable<Car> Cars
    {
        get { return this.CarOwners.Select(c => c.Car); }
    }
}
```

Or upgrade to Entity Framework where you can separate logical model from physical model.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `CarOwnerId` from `CarOwners` in your sql database. Then select `CarId` and `PersonId` in designer mode in SSMS (using shift key), right click and select `Set Primary Key.

In EF 4, you'll get only navigation keys in your model this way (you can use: `Person.Cars` and `Car.Persons`). Not sure about L2S.

Comment: A combined PK did not help :/ I think I will do this the @Jakub way